# Spring Boot loads component before its dependant bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

I have a weird behavior in my project using Spring. I have this structure:

```
Main-Spring-Project  
  |_Depends on Library A  
     |_Depends on Library B
```

Now... there is an @Autowired in a component in A which injects a component which is in B.
When I have all 3 projects opened in my development environment and start de main project, everythin works fine. But if I remove the project A and leave B, it all crashes when starting saying:

```
Field factory in [class in A] required a bean of type '[class in B]' that could not be found.
```

so... I suspect it is loading A, before B.
What I don't understand is why it works perfect if I have both projects open, and why it crashes when I have A closed (main project is using its JAR)

By the way... if I remove A and B, everything works perfect again.

Comment: After removing project A try doing project (main) clean build and then deploy. It may be because of old references.

Comment: Make sure all these are under `@ComponentScan`

Comment: They are... and if they weren't, it wouldn't work with the source projects either

Answer (score 0):

No Spring doesn't make a mistake during the context loading.
This behavior makes sense : the class is just not available at runtime.

Here you work with snapshot/current development source code/compiled classes of  library B since library B makes part of your current development code.
It means that  the dependencies/classes of library B needed during the run of the application doesn't depend on Maven for retrieving them but for what your IDE has access : the library A and B projects.

To avoid that you should `install` (`mvn clean install`) the `B` dependency in your local Maven/Gradle repository but that may be not practical if you need to repeat the task 20 days a day because the `B` source code changes 20 days a day.

Note that if you didn't use your IDE, you would be constraint to  install the dependency at each modification.   So finally, it is not so bad at all. No ?